# Dealing with Rows rather than Columns on my Android project

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, gridview

I have the following block of XML in declaring a gridview where I am using Columns.

The aim is to have five columns and five rows.

Can I also specify the number of Rows in it? If not, why not?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/gridView1"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
android:gravity="center"
android:columnWidth="50dp"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

</GridView>
```

Comment: The number of rows should depend on the size of your data source? You have control on that?

Comment: @Skynet Well my aim is to have 5 rows and 5 columns. But it seems to my previous searching that, in order to make the 5X5, I also have to specify the number of columns.

Comment: I have not worked much with Grids, however I wonder how five fixed coulmns would look like on a tab and the same five on a small 3.2 inches phone? Is it a good idea?

Comment: @Skynet Please focus on what is mentionned rather than discussing inputs which are already well-established. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can anyone give me feedback about it?